# WiFi not working Ubuntu 18.04 (with upgraded Kernel 5.19) on Razer Blade 15 eraly 2022

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, laptop

I recently got a new **Razer Blade 15 2022 (RZ09-0421PEF3-R3U1)**. Everything works perfectly on Windows 11, but a whole different story on **Ubuntu 18.04**. The most important issue is with the **WiFi card, which is not working**. The wifi spec is `Wi-Fi 6E, IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac/ax/az`

I searched for this issue, and all I could find was to upgrade the Ubuntu kernel to a newer version. I did this solution by upgrading to 5.19 and turning off the secure boot from BIOS, but the wifi still doesn't work.

Please let me know if there is any other solution to solve this issue since I need to work on Ubuntu 18.04, and if I can't fix this, I should return the laptop.

**UPDATE:** After adding 4 new firmware with the following commands:

> ```
> cd /lib/firmware
> sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-67.ucode
> sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-68.ucode
> sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-71.ucode
> sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode
> ```

The output of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` is:

> ```
> [    1.828532] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
> [    1.832993] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
> [    1.833004] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.36
> [    1.833362] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
> [    2.127761] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1690i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (411NGW), REV=0x370
> [    2.303495] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x3010d000
> [    2.305833] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
> [    2.305935] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
> [    2.305936] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
> [    2.305938] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode
> [    2.305940] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
> [    2.305941] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
> [    2.305942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
> [    2.305944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DB876 | branchlink2
> [    2.305945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink1
> [    2.305946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink2
> [    2.305947] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DA488 | data1
> [    2.305948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
> [    2.305949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
> [    2.305950] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
> [    2.305951] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000147F9 | tsf low
> [    2.305952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
> [    2.305953] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
> [    2.305954] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000295E0 | time gp2
> [    2.305955] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
> [    2.305956] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
> [    2.305957] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
> [    2.305958] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
> [    2.305959] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x40C89002 | board version
> [    2.305960] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x800BFD0D | hcmd
> [    2.305961] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
> [    2.305962] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000000 | isr1
> [    2.305963] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F00002 | isr2
> [    2.305964] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
> [    2.305965] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
> [    2.305966] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
> [    2.305967] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DA488 | wait_event
> [    2.305968] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
> [    2.305969] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
> [    2.305970] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
> [    2.305971] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
> [    2.305972] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
> [    2.305973] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
> [    2.305974] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000024 | flow_handler
> [    2.306056] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
> [    2.306058] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
> [    2.306060] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode
> [    2.306062] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
> [    2.306064] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
> [    2.306065] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
> [    2.306067] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DB876 | branchlink2
> [    2.306069] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink1
> [    2.306070] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink2
> [    2.306072] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004BD272 | data1
> [    2.306073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
> [    2.306075] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
> [    2.306076] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
> [    2.306078] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000147F9 | tsf low
> [    2.306080] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
> [    2.306081] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
> [    2.306083] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000295E0 | time gp2
> [    2.306084] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
> [    2.306086] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
> [    2.306088] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
> [    2.306089] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
> [    2.306091] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x40C89002 | board version
> [    2.306093] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x800CFD0D | hcmd
> [    2.306094] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
> [    2.306096] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
> [    2.306097] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F00002 | isr2
> [    2.306099] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
> [    2.306100] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
> [    2.306102] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
> [    2.306104] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004BD272 | wait_event
> [    2.306105] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
> [    2.306107] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
> [    2.306109] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
> [    2.306110] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
> [    2.306112] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
> [    2.306113] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
> [    2.306115] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000024 | flow_handler
> [    2.306163] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
> [    2.306165] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
> [    2.306167] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PNVM data is missing, please install iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0.pnvm
> [    2.306169] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2010070D | PNVM_MISSING
> [    2.306171] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
> [    2.306173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x804603E0 | umac branchlink2
> [    2.306174] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0109C12A | umac interruptlink1
> [    2.306176] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
> [    2.306178] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000005 | umac data1
> [    2.306179] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
> [    2.306181] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
> [    2.306182] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | umac major
> [    2.306184] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
> [    2.306186] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000295D9 | frame pointer
> [    2.306187] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0885EA8 | stack pointer
> [    2.306189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
> [    2.306190] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
> [    2.306224] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
> [    2.306225] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
> [    2.306274] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000080B0 | IML/ROM data1
> [    2.306284] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
> [    2.306291] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
> [    2.306335] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000011 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
> [    2.306339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80520001 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
> [    2.306342] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00190002 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
> [    2.306346] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A657 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
> [    2.306390] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000006 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
> [    2.306394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
> [    2.306398] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
> [    2.306401] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00480410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
> [    2.306445] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
> [    2.306451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00480410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
> [    2.306457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
> [    2.306503] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
> [    2.306522] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
> [    3.004149] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
> [    3.016647] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 0
> [    3.026755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1690i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (411NGW), REV=0x370
> [    3.270832] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
> [    3.270932] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
> [    3.270932] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
> [    3.270933] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode
> [    3.270934] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
> [    3.270935] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
> [    3.270936] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
> [    3.270936] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DB876 | branchlink2
> [    3.270937] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink1
> [    3.270937] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink2
> [    3.270937] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DA488 | data1
> [    3.270938] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
> [    3.270938] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
> [    3.270939] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
> [    3.270939] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00013467 | tsf low
> [    3.270940] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
> [    3.270940] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
> [    3.270941] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00028068 | time gp2
> [    3.270941] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
> [    3.270942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
> [    3.270942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
> [    3.270943] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
> [    3.270943] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x58C89002 | board version
> [    3.270943] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x800BFD0D | hcmd
> [    3.270944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
> [    3.270944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000000 | isr1
> [    3.270945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F00002 | isr2
> [    3.270945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
> [    3.270946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
> [    3.270946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
> [    3.270946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DA488 | wait_event
> [    3.270947] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
> [    3.270947] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
> [    3.270948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
> [    3.270948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
> [    3.270949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
> [    3.270949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
> [    3.270949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000024 | flow_handler
> [    3.271033] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
> [    3.271034] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
> [    3.271034] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode
> [    3.271035] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
> [    3.271035] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
> [    3.271036] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
> [    3.271036] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DB876 | branchlink2
> [    3.271037] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink1
> [    3.271037] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink2
> [    3.271037] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004BD272 | data1
> [    3.271038] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
> [    3.271038] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
> [    3.271039] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
> [    3.271039] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00013467 | tsf low
> [    3.271040] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
> [    3.271040] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
> [    3.271040] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00028068 | time gp2
> [    3.271041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
> [    3.271041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
> [    3.271042] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
> [    3.271042] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
> [    3.271043] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x58C89002 | board version
> [    3.271043] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x800CFD0D | hcmd
> [    3.271044] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
> [    3.271044] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
> [    3.271044] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F00002 | isr2
> [    3.271045] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
> [    3.271045] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
> [    3.271046] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
> [    3.271046] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004BD272 | wait_event
> [    3.271047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
> [    3.271047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
> [    3.271047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
> [    3.271048] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
> [    3.271048] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
> [    3.271049] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
> [    3.271049] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000024 | flow_handler
> [    3.271100] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
> [    3.271101] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
> [    3.271102] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PNVM data is missing, please install iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0.pnvm
> [    3.271102] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2010070D | PNVM_MISSING
> [    3.271103] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
> [    3.271103] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x804603E0 | umac branchlink2
> [    3.271104] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0109C12A | umac interruptlink1
> [    3.271104] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
> [    3.271105] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000005 | umac data1
> [    3.271105] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
> [    3.271106] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
> [    3.271106] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | umac major
> [    3.271106] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
> [    3.271107] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00028062 | frame pointer
> [    3.271107] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0885EA8 | stack pointer
> [    3.271108] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
> [    3.271108] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
> [    3.271150] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
> [    3.271150] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
> [    3.271158] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000080B4 | IML/ROM data1
> [    3.271166] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
> [    3.271171] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
> [    3.271173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
> [    3.271176] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80520001 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
> [    3.271178] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00190002 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
> [    3.271180] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A657 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
> [    3.271183] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000006 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
> [    3.271185] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
> [    3.271187] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
> [    3.271189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00480410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
> [    3.271192] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
> [    3.271196] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00480410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
> [    3.271200] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
> [    3.271205] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
> [    3.271309] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
> [    3.965406] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
> [    3.977712] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 1
> [    3.988582] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1690i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (411NGW), REV=0x370
> [    4.161453] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
> [    4.162728] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
> [    4.185035] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
> [    4.185036] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode
> [    4.185037] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
> [    4.185037] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
> [    4.185038] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
> [    4.185038] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DB876 | branchlink2
> [    4.185039] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink1
> [    4.185039] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink2
> [    4.185040] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DA488 | data1
> [    4.185040] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
> [    4.185041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
> [    4.185041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
> [    4.185041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000135A0 | tsf low
> [    4.185042] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
> [    4.185042] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
> [    4.185043] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000281A0 | time gp2
> [    4.185043] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
> [    4.185043] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
> [    4.185044] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
> [    4.185044] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
> [    4.185045] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x58C89002 | board version
> [    4.185045] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x800BFD0D | hcmd
> [    4.185045] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
> [    4.185046] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000000 | isr1
> [    4.185046] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F00002 | isr2
> [    4.185047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
> [    4.185047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
> [    4.185047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
> [    4.185048] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DA488 | wait_event
> [    4.185048] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
> [    4.185049] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
> [    4.185049] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
> [    4.185049] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
> [    4.185050] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
> [    4.185050] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
> [    4.185051] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000024 | flow_handler
> [    4.185138] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
> [    4.215869] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
> [    4.215870] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode
> [    4.215870] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
> [    4.215871] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
> [    4.215871] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
> [    4.215872] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DB876 | branchlink2
> [    4.215872] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink1
> [    4.215872] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D154A | interruptlink2
> [    4.215873] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004BD272 | data1
> [    4.215873] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
> [    4.215874] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
> [    4.215874] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
> [    4.215874] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000135A0 | tsf low
> [    4.215875] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
> [    4.215875] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
> [    4.215876] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000281A0 | time gp2
> [    4.215876] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
> [    4.215876] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | uCode version major
> [    4.215877] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | uCode version minor
> [    4.215877] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
> [    4.215878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x58C89002 | board version
> [    4.215878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x800CFD0D | hcmd
> [    4.215879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
> [    4.215879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
> [    4.215879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F00002 | isr2
> [    4.215880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
> [    4.215880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
> [    4.215880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
> [    4.215881] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004BD272 | wait_event
> [    4.215881] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
> [    4.215882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
> [    4.215882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
> [    4.215882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
> [    4.215883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
> [    4.215883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
> [    4.215884] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000024 | flow_handler
> [    4.215938] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
> [    4.215938] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
> [    4.215939] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PNVM data is missing, please install iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0.pnvm
> [    4.215939] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2010070D | PNVM_MISSING
> [    4.215940] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
> [    4.215940] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x804603E0 | umac branchlink2
> [    4.215941] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0109C12A | umac interruptlink1
> [    4.215941] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
> [    4.215942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000005 | umac data1
> [    4.215942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
> [    4.215942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
> [    4.215943] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000048 | umac major
> [    4.215943] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
> [    4.215944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0002819A | frame pointer
> [    4.215944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0885EA8 | stack pointer
> [    4.215944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
> [    4.215945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
> [    4.215987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
> [    4.215988] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
> [    4.215995] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000080A3 | IML/ROM data1
> [    4.258544] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
> [    4.258549] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
> [    4.258551] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
> [    4.258553] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80520001 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
> [    4.258555] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00190002 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
> [    4.258558] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A657 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
> [    4.258560] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000006 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
> [    4.258562] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
> [    4.258564] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
> [    4.258567] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00480410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
> [    4.258569] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
> [    4.258573] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00480410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
> [    4.258578] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
> [    4.258582] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
> [    4.258690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
> [    4.952109] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
> [    4.964481] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2
> ```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Take note of the listed kernel driver. Then run and include: `sudo dmesg | grep <driver_you_found>` For example: `sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi` We suspect you need newer firmware. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks. I updated the question with terminal output as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we suspected, you require firmware. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, please open a terminal and do:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-67.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-68.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-71.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode
```

Reboot and again show us:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

**EDIT:** Let’s try a different method. Please do:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo rm iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0*
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-67.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-68.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-71.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-72.ucode
```

Reboot and again show us:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

**EDIT2:** Please do:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0.pnvm
```

Reboot and show us:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: I did that and for this 4 new firmware I just added the output says:
`[    1.799959] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: uCode file size 10518386 does not match expected size

[    1.807272] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: uCode file size 10420898 does not match expected size

[    1.814303] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: uCode file size 10325310 does not match expected size

[    1.821299] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: uCode file size 10256552 does not match expected size
`
The rest of the output is same as before.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: I updated the question with the terminal output you requested.

Comment: Please see my Edit 2.

Comment: OMG! Yeah it finally worked!
I'm sending this comment with a WiFi internet connection! :)
Thank you for your step-by-step guide and support.

Comment: I will mark your answer as "accepted," so it might also help others.

Comment: Hi,
I reinstalled ubuntu 18.04 and upgraded the kernel to 5.19 but I can't fix my WiFi with the provided answer. could you please help me again?

Comment: Please start a new question and include the result of: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`